# Start docker container through an entry point function with arguments

Tags: python, image, docker, containers

Suppose I have a file called `handler.py` inside a docker container (which is not yet running or up from image). Let the image name be `testimage`.

Inside `handler.py`, we have a function `greet` such that

```
def greet(username):
    print("Hello %s!"%(username))
```

Now I want to start my docker container from this image such that I invoke this function `greet` inside the file `handler.py` along with an argument. I want to call this while creating a running container itself.

Comment: Where from do you want to start the docker container with the image and the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you're asking two things. One how to call a function in a python file from commandline. Two how to do this via Docker.

For the first, in the handler.py you'd need a main function to be able to do this. Something like this for example.

```
import sys


def greet(username):
    print("Hello %s!"%(username))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    greet(sys.argv[1])
```

Running it gives:

```
$ python handler.py harshvardhan
Hello harshvardhan!
```

Alternative and more complex is using OptionParser and switches based on that.
Depending on your usecase, either works.

For the docker, I think you don't want to change the entrypoint, but the CMD. Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY handler.py .

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python2.7"]
CMD ["/app/handler.py"]
```

Build an image:

```
$ docker build . -t local:dev
```

Run it, overriding the `CMD`:

```
$ docker run local:dev /app/handler.py itismemario
Hello itismemario!
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I was confused about entrypoint. Since long I was providing entrypoint as handler.py and was getting error. Your suggestion to provide python location as entrypoint solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the python script execution command during docker run as below,

`docker run <image> python handler.py --user username_value`.

And make sure you have handled that args using argparse in handler.py and call your greet function.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('--user', help='username', required=True, type=str)
```